# Error while creating a product in express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

While creating a product in node,it shows an error and does not let me create the product, I modified the model to see if it was something wrong structured and still shows error, when sending the data by postman in the console it seems that no data was sent with the post method.

Error

```
 this.$__.validationError = new ValidationError(this);
                               ^

ValidationError: Products validation failed: nombre: Por favor ingrese el nombre del producto

properties: {
        validator: [Function (anonymous)],
        message: 'Por favor ingrese el nombre del producto',
        type: 'required',
        path: 'nombre',
        value: undefined
      },
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'nombre',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
  },
  _message: 'Products validation failed'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

I don't know what the problem is or why the error is being generated, I still haven't figured it out.

code controller

```
export const newProduct = async (res, req) => {
    const product = await productModel.create(req.body);
    res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        data: product,
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you change the places of "req" and "res". It should look like this; (req, res)
                Besides, it is always good practice to wrap async actions in the try-catch method

Comment: That's exactly what it was, you're a genius. Thank you very much crack